# How do we log to stdout with gofiber golang framework?

Tags: go, logging, go-fiber

I am looking for a way to log some data to stdout with gofiber golang framework as the framework is very quiet and does not log errors mostly

I was thinking i could just use `fmf.Print` but even that does not get picked up at all

How do you guys troubleshoot with the gofiber framework? How i can detect issues within the code when the framework rarely spits anything out.

Here is what i am trying to do for example **but getting nothing still in stdout**

```
func GetUserEmail(c *fiber.Ctx) (string, error) {
    cookie := c.Cookies("access_token")

    token, err := jwt.ParseWithClaims(cookie, &ClaimsWithScope{}, func(token *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
        return []byte(SecretKey), nil
    })

    if err != nil {
        return "issues found", err
    }


    payload := token.Claims.(*ClaimsWithScope)

    email := payload.Subject
    fmt.Print("email is", email, "\n")
    return email, nil
}
```

from above i have this line `fmt.Print("email is", email, "\n")` to print the value of `email` to stdout so i can troubleshoot **but nothing gets printed at all**

Need to make gofiber verbose to troubleshoot issues

Comment: what's the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fmt.Println("email is", email, "\n")
```

does work, issue was code was not getting to that point; finally moved it higher up in the code and can now see prints in stdout

Answer (score 0):

To parse a JWT with claims or custom claims you should check the status.

```
// pass your custom claims to the parser function and data type of cookie parameter should be string
    token, err := jwt.ParseWithClaims(cookie, &ClaimsWithScope{}, func(token *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
        if _, ok := token.Method.(*jwt.SigningMethodHMAC); !ok {
            return nil, errors.New("unexpected signing method")
        }
        return []byte(/* your JWT secret*/), nil
    })

    // type-assert `Claims` into a variable of the appropriate type
    payload := token.Claims.(*ClaimsWithScope)
```

If you didn't see any output with `fmt.Print()` then you have to use `fmt.Println()`.

[Print](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt#Print) :- "Print" This cannot format anything, it simply takes a string and print it

[Println](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt#Println) :- "Print Line" same thing as `Printf()` however it will append a newline character`\n`

Comment: able to see the prints now...btw needed help with printing to stdout not with the function i had